# Cannot find link between trigonometric statements and reduced form

Tags: integration, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have been trying to find a way to reduce following trigonometric statements to the reduced form below, but without succes.
I haven't been able to grasp the typical train of thought I presume I would start off with before tackling the following two. These two steps occurred in two separate exercises on integrals and polar curves.

1) I would like to reduce the left side to the right:

$$\cos^{8}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)+\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right) = \cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right).$$

2) I would like to reduce the left side to the right:
$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot \cos(\theta)+\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot \sin(\theta)=\sin\left(\frac{5}{4}\theta\right).$$

Comment: But, anyway, for the first one, think about $\sin^2A+\cos^2A$; for the second, think about $\sin(A+B)$.

Comment: Thank you. I can't relate the first one to the identity yet though, how would I do that?

Comment: By factoring, Katie.

Comment: For the first one, rewrite the first term on the left as $\cos^6(\theta/4) \cos^2(\theta/4)$.  Then see if you can take advantage of Gerry's hints.

Comment: Okay, there's a mistake I won't dare to make again. Thank you both.

Comment: My pleasure.  We've all been there. :)

Comment: Let me encourage you, Katie, to write up and post an answer to your question, as it appears you now understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Using the Pythagorean identity**:

$$\cos^{8}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)+\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)$$

$$=\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)+\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)$$

$$=\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot\left[\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)+\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\right]$$
$$=\cos^{6}\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)$$

2) **Using sum- and addition formula**

$\sin\left(\alpha+\beta\right)= \sin\left(\alpha\right)\cos\left(\beta\right)+\sin\left(\beta\right)\cos\left(\alpha\right)$ :

$$\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right)\cdot \cos(\theta)+\sin\left(\theta\right)\cdot\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{4}\right) $$

$$=\sin\left(\frac{5\theta}{4}\right)$$

Thanks to Gerry Myerson and John in the comments above.